# Is there request caching in NodeJS between multiple runs?

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a simple js file that I'm running with node, eg. `node index.js` from the command line.

The script uses `axios` to POST data to an endpoint. How is it possible that if I say the data is `{id: 10}`, run the script, change `{id: 50}`, save and run the script again both POST calls still post `{id: 10}`?

Am I missing some caching that's in between?

Thanks

Comment: how is this possible to answer your question without providing some code?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such caching mechanism. Some proxy between you and the server could eventually be caching, but normally no proxy will cache a `POST` request.

Comment: Funnily when I try to do that via Postman, everything works as expected

Comment: Try running a network sniffer, you will see. There is nothing that allows Node to cache the JS content of the files it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the issue was with the API. As soon as I send the data as `form-data`, everything works as expected. If I try `application/json`, weird stuff happens.